# Parse - callFunctionInBackground crashes app on [__NSTaggedDate UTF8String] - But did not when I submitted my app

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm using a Parse Cloud function to get a list of movies. This was all working very well till today. The app crashes and I can't seem to fix it.
Weird (and highly problematic) thing is that it did work yesterday and the days before. (This app is in production in the App store)

This is the function causing the error:

```
PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground(function, withParameters: parameters) { (movies, error) -> Void in
  if error != nil { return block(success: false, movies: []) }
  PFObject.pinAllInBackground(movies as! [PFObject])
  let foundMovies = ParseMovie.arrayFromPFObjects(movies as! [PFObject])
  return block(success: true, movies: foundMovies)
}
```

If I comment the 4 lines inside the block, it still crashes. If I comment the entire function, it doesn't. So it seems as soon as I call "**PFCloud.callFunction**" the app crashes.

Any idea what can go wrong? The Parse cloud function does work, because calling it with the parse rest API gives me the movies as expected.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it. Apparently I'm using an old version of the Parse SDK (1.5) and since today, this version is not working anymore.. I'm not using pods so I was not aware of this out-dated version. A bit disappointed, but probably my fault?